# PHP MySql - Update is not updating

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem with my update query. It does not show any syntax error, but also does not update a database.

```
        // SQL
        $sql = 'UPDATE pizza_info
                SET name = :name, price = :price
                WHERE id = :id';

        try{
            $update = $db->prepare($sql);
            $update->execute(array(':name' => $this->name, ':price' => $this->price, ':id' => $this->id));
            if($update->rowCount() != 1){
                throw new PDOException('No row changed');
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            ErrorPages::generalError();
            die();
        }
```

But if I try to put same values directly into sql like that:

```
        // SQL
        $sql = 'UPDATE pizza_info
                SET name = "Test", price = "55"
                WHERE id = 1';

        try{
            $update = $db->prepare($sql);
            $update->execute();
            if($update->rowCount() != 1){
                throw new PDOException('No row changed');
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            ErrorPages::generalError();
            die();
        }
```

The first method work in another queries and updates well, but in this case does not. I try to debug that, but i could not find anything.

Have somebody some idea, where could be a problem?
Thanks.

Comment: is this in a class, as you are using `$this->`? Are your variable in scope?

Comment: Yes, this code is in method in class. Variables are set right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the point on prepared statements. The values should not go directly in the string, but are instead bound with the bind_param function. This way even if you use direct POST injection, the query will always be secure:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE pizza_info
                SET name = :name, price = :price
                WHERE id = :id';

$update = $db->prepare($sql);
$update->execute(array(':name'=>'Test',':price'=>55,':id'=>1));
```

Look at the documentation on execute
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

---

My full code for reference:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');

// SQL
$sql = 'UPDATE pizza_info
        SET name = :name, price = :price
        WHERE id = :id';

try{
    $update = $db->prepare($sql);
    $update->execute(array(':name' => 'Test', ':price' => 55, ':id' => 1));
    echo $update->rowCount();
    if($update->rowCount() != 1){
        throw new PDOException('No row changed');
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    ErrorPages::generalError();
    die();
}
```

With the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pizza_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `pizza_info` (`id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'a', 1);
```

Comment: (1) You have to `->prepare()` the query before you can bind the parms. (2)[`->bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is a `mysqli` function, PDO is [`->bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). (3) Also, OP's method of using [`->execute(arrary(...))`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is the same as doing [`->bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: I read over it too fast, the example is actually in the question.

Comment: If i use bind_param, it shows me undefined method error and if I try bindParam, it shows me error `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Comment: But if I change `$update->execute(array(':name' => $this->name, ':price' => $this->price, ':id' => $this->id));` on this `$update->execute(array(':name' => 'Now', ':price' => '45', ':id' => 1));` it update it in database, but PHP still show me error, when no rows was changed.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the incomplete answer. The easiest is what you did last. You'd get that error if nothing has changed. Check if the record in the database with id 1 already has that name and price.. it would if you run it twice for example.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I try again `$update->execute(array(':name' => $this->name, ':price' => $this->price, ':id' => $this->id));` and it updates in database, but `$update->rowCount()` return 0, even when row was updated.

Comment: For your benefit I actually tried this code and made a new table pizza_info with those fields and added a row with id=1,name=a,price=1. Then I used your code to `$update->execute(array(':name' => 'Test', ':price' => 55, ':id' => 1));` and `echo $update->rowCount()` gives me 1.. Of course when you reload then I also get the error, because the second time it is not actually changed, so affectedRows (rowCount) is 0.

Comment: I dont now why, but me it returns 0. Maybe it is becouse it runs twice, how you wrote. I try to look at a code and try to find somethinf, what could do that.

Comment: I've added my complete code for reference. First execute should produce "1" and nothing else, which it did for me.

Comment: rowCount in another update works well. I look at another code and I try fix a problem. And thank you for help.